# iOS - UIWebView loading HTML string contains iframe not working

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm trying to load HTML String containing iframe to `UIWebview` the view takes the space of the content but it loads totally blank view here is the HTML

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='charset=utf-8'/>
  <style>
   iframe{max-width:100% !important} 
  </style>
 </head>
     <body>
         <p dir="RTL"> <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="573" id="molvideoplayer" scrolling="no" src="http://www.dailymail.co.uk/embed/video/1411595.html" title="MailOnline Embed Player" width="698"></iframe> </p> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

aslo my code is

```
self.newsBodyWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

Also I tried the UIWebView delegate function

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

and I got this error

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

I searched the error but nothing helped out.

When I removed the iframe and wrote any other html the UIWebView worked perfectly.

I don't know what's wrong with my code

**EDIT**

When I press any button to make changes in the container view the webview appears again, I am confused why this happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out, the web view height was set after webview finish launching this way

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
     webView.frame.size.height = 1
     self.webViewHeight = webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
}
```

I changed this to

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
     webView.frame.size.height = 1
     let height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
     var wvRect = webView.frame
     wvRect.size.height = height
     webView.frame = wvRect
}
```

and every thing is working fine now.